# Stop-update-start with saltstack highstate?

Tags: web-applications, updates, salt-stack

Saltstack is responsible for updating web application code (uwsgi, Python, if it matters). The idea is to update the code from an archive. It would be nice to use a single salt command for that - `state.highstate`.

The problem is, that during update the application code should not be running, so `service.stop` and `service.start` are run around the  `state.highstate`.

Is there any way to include this update logic into highstate? Or maybe there is some other command, which is more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in the Mastering SaltStack, 2nd edition by Joseph Hall the following.

> ..., consider a web application that makes use of Apache. When
>   the codebase on a production server changes, Apache should be turned
>   off, so as to avoid errors with the code that has not yet finished
>   being installed.

The key is to use `prereq`, here is book's example adapted to my archive case:

```
my_service: 
  service: 
    - running
    - name: my_service
    - watch: 
      - cmd: my_archive

my_archive: 
  cmd: 
    - run
    - name: "/bin/tar -zxf my.tar.gz -C {{ code_dir }}"
    - require:
      - file: my.tar.gz
    ... 

shutdown_my_service: 
  service: 
    - dead 
    - name: my_service 
    - prereq: 
      - cmd: my_archive
```

(I have not checked it exactly as written here, but it's easy to see the idea)